# My OS boots to Bash

Tags: boot

I was installing  the companion app for Video Downloadhelper
the instruction I used had the following set of commands and explanation at the end

---

> 4. Amending User’s Path
>
> Again Append Video DownloadHelper into the Path
> This is needed only to run the App easily from Command Line…

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/opt/net.downloadhelper.coapp/bin' >> ~/.bashrc
```

> Finally, Reload the Bash User’s Path simply with:

```
bash
```

---

And now when I boot the OS I have to type `exit` in order to continue with the loading of the OS
I am certain that this can be undone I just don't know the command syntax
Do you know how  to undo that?

I ran `ls -a` and  got this:

```
 ls -a
.              Desktop      .mozilla             .ssh
..             Documents    Music                .sudo_as_admin_successful
.bash_history  Downloads    .nvidia-settings-rc  Templates
.bash_logout   dwhelper     Pictures             .thunderbird
.bashrc        .fontconfig  .profile             Videos
.cache         .gnupg       Public
.config        .local       snap
```

Comment: Bad idea following anything from the internet and doing things without knowing what they do. You added that path to the bashrc file. Edit the .bashrc file and remove what you added.

Comment: Can we have a link to where you found the instructions?

Comment: It's hard to imagine how adding a component to the *end* of your `PATH` in the startup file for *interactive* bash shells would have any effect on the boot sequence - what were steps 1-3?

Comment: @steeldriver I suspect what they mean is, when they log in, they get dumped into a terminal. But it's definitely unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Do from command line:

`vi ~/.bashrc`

<kbd>ESC</kbd>`/downloadhelper`

and that should have the cursor go to this text in the file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/net.downloadhelper.coapp/bin
```

If so do `dd` and it will remove the line then <kbd>ESC</kbd>`:wq` to exit.

That will remove the line and should fix the problem. Log out and in and see if it continues without stopping.

And then see how to add that bit to your PATH correctly.

Comment: Rinzwind asked for this:   https://tutorialforlinux.com/2020/12/26/step-by-step-video-downloadhelper-companion-app-ubuntu-18-04-installation/

Comment: besides it mentioning 18.04 I do not see anything wrong with the command :P

Comment: Vim was  confusing me, I made sure Vim was installed, I was getting a help screen when I entered that.   So I used gedit, removed the line, saved, and the issue persists.   It's a new install I only have 69 entries in the Bash history

Comment: Me neither, I searched the term and the only variant I found was some  spell  out  the complete word "vim."  Same result.  I have the Linux book "The Command Line"  There is precious little on Bash or Vim in it.